# two quick fix issues - Merge Sort

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, mergesort

I have created my version of the merge sort algorithm in java code. My issues are these: when I run the code as is, I get a NullPointerExecpetion in the main on line 27 (see commented line). And I know there is way to make the method calls and instantiate newArray without them being static but Im not quite sure how.. can someone help fix these? I am still relatively new to java so be nice :)

Main:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MergeSort_main 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] originalArray = new int[1000];
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++)
    {
        int randNum = rand.nextInt(1000)+1;
        originalArray[i] = randNum;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i+"." + originalArray[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("---------------------End Random Array-------\n");

    MergeSortAlgorithm.mergeSortAlg(originalArray);
    int[] sortedArray = MergeSortAlgorithm.getSortedArray();


    for(int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION HERE
    {
        System.out.println(i+ "." + sortedArray[i]);
    }

   }    
}
```

Algorithm Class:

```
public class MergeSortAlgorithm 
{

private static int[] newArray;


 public static void mergeSortAlg(int[] randomNums) 
 {       
        int size = randomNums.length;

        if (size < 2)
        {
            return; //if the array can not be split up further, stop attempting to split. 
        }
        int half = size / 2;

        int firstHalfNums = half;
        int secondHalfNums = size - half;

        int[] firstArray = new int[firstHalfNums];
        int[] secondArray = new int[secondHalfNums];

        for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) 
        {
            firstArray[i] = randomNums[i];
        }

        for (int i = half; i < size; i++) 
        {
            secondArray[i - half] = randomNums[i];
        }
        mergeSortAlg(firstArray);
        mergeSortAlg(secondArray);
        merge(firstArray, secondArray, randomNums);
    }

    public static void merge(int[] firstArray, int[] secondArray, int[] newArray) 
    {
        int firstHalfNums = firstArray.length;
        int secondHalfNums = secondArray.length;
        int i = 0; //iterator for firstArray
        int j = 0; //iterator for second array
        int k = 0; //interator for randomNums array

        while (i < firstHalfNums && j < secondHalfNums) 
        {
            if (firstArray[i] <= secondArray[j]) 
            {
                newArray[k] = firstArray[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            } 
            else 
            {
                newArray[k] = secondArray[j];
                k++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        while (i < firstHalfNums) 
        {
            newArray[k] = firstArray[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        while (j < firstHalfNums) 
        {
            newArray[k] = secondArray[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }  


    }

    public static int[] getSortedArray()
    {
        return newArray;
    }


}
```

Comment: Well, you never instantiate `newArray` (or assign **any** value to it), so when you `getSortedArray` it returns `null`.  Hence the NPE when you try to evaluate `sortedArray.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the only problem with your code is that you don't initialize `newArray` with any values, resulting in a `null`.

You are also redefining `newArray` at the top of your `merge` function .

Comment: @ahitt66345 But my issue is when I initialize it to lets say newArray= {0}; the value never changes in the code and it returns the value of newArrary as 0.0

Comment: Here's the thing though, where do you initialize `newArray`?

Comment: when you call `getSortedArray`, you return your private instance of the `newArray` variable. Which does not have anything.

Comment: I get i am confused for some reason, why isn't the value of newArray changing?

Comment: Wait, in your `merge` function, you are redefining `newArray` in your parameter area.

Comment: Yeah, but that is just a parameter name I pass it, I can name that anything I want and it will still return  0 for newArray

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96100/discussion-between-ahitt6345-and-user3712626).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that newArray[] is never instantiated i.e. newArray reference is pointing to null. And, no change is made in the newArray so value or reference returned to main is null. And, then you are performing `sortedArray.length` where sorted array having a null value.

You have to make newArray[] point to randomNums[].